# How to properly shutdown process in windows with python?

Tags: python, windows, process, signals, sigterm

I run `ffmpeg` from `python` script and need to shutdown recording on demand.
In Linux I just send `SIGTERM`. But in Windows as I understand `SIGTERM` replaced by `SIGKILL` so records needs to be remixed to play properly.
After googling I found that I should use `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` but this signal terminate my parent script too.

What should I use?

Comment: In order to send `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`, the child process needs to be attached to the same console as the parent and created with the flag `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`. The child cannot be created with any of the following flags: `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`, or `DETACHED_PROCESS`.

Comment: Otherwise if we try to send Ctrl+Break to a non-console child, or a child that's attached to a different console, or a child that's not the leader of a console process group, the system has undefined and quite buggy behavior. It shouldn't. These cases should all have well-defined, documented behavior. I opened an issue for this months ago on the console's GitHub site, but the console devs don't seem to be interested.